# Dual of $L^1(\mu)$ in general...

Tags: measure-theory

I've been wondering about the dual of $L^1(\mu)$ when $\mu$ is not $\sigma$-finite.

Just got a copy of Cohn *Measure Theory*. I  see various results showing the dual is $L^\infty$ for some non-$\sigma$-finite  measures, but of course that's simply not true for a general measure; so far I don't see anything about what the dual actually  *is* in general. I'm wondering:

Say $g$ is *locally meaasurable* if $g\chi_E$ is measurable for every measurable  set $E$ with $\mu(E)<\infty$ (equivalently, if $fg$ is measurable for every $f\in L^1$).

> > **Question.** Suppose $\mu$ is a measure and $\Lambda\in L^1(\mu)^*$. Does it follow that there exists  a bounded locally measurable function $g$ with $\Lambda f = \int fg$?

Probably it's a standard counterexample and I'm just being ignorant again.  But the few counterexamples to $(L^1)^*=L^\infty$ that I know are not counterexamples to this:

**Example.** Say $X$ is an uncountable set, $A$ is the algebra of countable or co-countable sets, and $\mu$ is counting measure on $X$, restricted to $A$. It's  easy to see that if $\Lambda\in (L^1)^*$ then there exists a bounded  function $g$ with $\Lambda f=\int fg$, and here *every* function is locally measurable. (If $g$ is bounded and not mesasurable then $f\mapsto\int fg$ is an element of $(L^1)^*$ that is not induced by an  $L^\infty$ function.)

**Warning:** If like me you find yourself skimming through Cohn without  reading the first few chapters carefully, Proposition 3.3.5 will seem clearly false:

> > **Cohn 3.3.5, paraphrased.** If $\mu$ is a measure and $g\in L^\infty(\mu)$ then $||g||_\infty=||g||_{(L^1)^*}$.

$\newcommand\set[1]{\{#1\}}$
**Apparent Counterexample.** Let $X=\set{1,2}$, $\mu(\set 0)=1$, $\mu(\set 1)=\infty$. Let $g=\chi_{\set 1}$. Then $||g||_\infty=1$, $||g||_{(L^1)^*}=0$.

**Resolution.** Cohn's $||g||_\infty$ is not what you think. Say the measurable set $N$  is *locally null* if $\mu(N\cap E)=0$ for every measurable set $E$ with $\mu(E)<\infty$. He defines $||g||_\infty$ to be the infimum of the $M$ such that $\set{x:|f(x)|\ge M}$ is locally null. (Of course in the $\sigma$-finite case that's equivalent to what seems to me to be the more standard definition.)

(If anyone familiar with the book pointed out other similar sources of possible Cohnfusion that would be appreciated...)

Comment: This might be relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/405357/when-exactly-is-the-dual-of-l1-isomorphic-to-l-infty-via-the-natural-map

Comment: Indeed, the business of patching functions together is exactly what comes up if one tries to show the answer to the question is yes...